# Store vectors in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am starting to work with **SQLite** in **Qt Creator**. I never worked with **SQLite** before. How can I create a table to store the following data?

```
int id;
QString fullName;
int age;
QVector<QString> friendsFirstName;
QVector<QString> friendsSurname;
```

In fact, my doubt is how to store vectors that must be linked to a single record? **SQLite** provides some vector type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some basic types.
You can however use the BLOB type to save whatever you want.
Are you going to do the vector processing outside to SQLite?

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

- NULL. The value is a NULL value.
- INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
  bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
- REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE
  floating point number.
- TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding
  (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
- BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Comment: Thanks @Dudu Markovitz. Yes, I will process the vectors outside of SQLite. I will search about the BLOB type, I never used it before.

Comment: Binary Large OBject

Comment: Great. Then BLOB is independent of the vector data type !?

Comment: Yes. You can use It basically to store everything.

Comment: Wonderful, it is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.